# AG-Grid: How to save and reload the filter in AG-Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

Using AG-Grid, Users can use filters in the way they like. I need to allow the user to save the filter , so that it becomes the default filter for them.

```
const onGridReady = (params) => {
   
    var filterState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myfilterState"));

    if (filterState) {
      params.api.setFilterModel(filterState);
    }
};
```

```
 const DisplayedColumnsChanged = (params) => {
    var filterState = JSON.stringify(params.api.getFilterModel());
    localStorage.setItem("myfilterState", filterState);
  };
```

Using this, I am not able to save and reload the filters.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Are you sure the object is being saved to LS, and that it's being loaded again correctly?

Comment: @Andy No error is showing there, and using the same method , I save and reload the column order